# Randomize and Sample using SQL in Excel VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba, sampling

I am using VBA for Excel and I have a workbook with a few tabs. I would like to randomize and pull a sample from each tab. An example of the code is below

```
   sql = "SELECT TOP " & myNum & " * " & _
   "FROM [Annual$] ORDER BY RND()"
      
   Debug.Print sql
```

Individually, both parts of this code works as intended. Together, however, I receive a random sample but I am no longer able to limit it. I am limited in VBA code with other options (to my understanding) but if there is a way to implement LIMIT instead of SELECT TOP then that could solve this but I don't believe Excel is capable of this.

Here is the debug print:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Annual$] ORDER BY RND()
```

Comment: "Both parts" but I only see one part. I think. Also, there is no different between `TOP` that is used in JET or ACE or whatever underlying engine windows is using these days and `LIMIT` used in RDBMS's like Mysql or Mariadb. So I'm not sure what the issue is and I don't think your hopeful fix is doable or would make any difference. Can you share more about what's working and what isn't?

Comment: @JNevill of course! The first part is "SELECT TOP" and the second part is "ORDER BY RND()", I apologize for not being explicit here. My goal is have a user inputted number (this is stored into "myNum") and to use this to pull an exact n size sample from the other tabs. I need the sample to be randomized. I've tried "LIMIT" but it doesn't work for me unfortunately.

Comment: Curious. So when you add the `ORDER BY` you get more than one record back? That's some ugly buggy nonsense!

Comment: What if you subquery it: `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (SELECT * FROM [Annual$] ORDER BY RND()) as sub;`?

Comment: @JNevill in short, for testing purposes, I want to return 1 random row. I always receive the full dataset. So I am trying to find a better way to limit this.

Comment: I can try that! Give me one moment

Comment: How odd. I will post as an answer in case anyone else should ever run into that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently there must be some bug in the sql engine in use under the hood that adding that `ORDER BY` causes `TOP` to be ignored. Breaking the logic of the sql down to do the `ORDER BY` in a subquery and the `TOP` in the outside query appears to circumvent this bug:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (SELECT * FROM [Annual$] ORDER BY RND()) as sub;
```

Comment: Nice work creating a workaround that is still readable.